# Update many-to-many entity with ASP.NET Core MVC MultiSelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a form where I want to update an entity with a many-to-many relationship with another entity, and I'm trying to use the `select` tag to create the `MultiSelectList` control. I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 with Entity Framework.

Say I have the following entities:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentCourse> Students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

The view model:

```cs
public class StudentVM
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CourseList { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```cshtml
@model StudentVM
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select asp-for="CourseList" asp-items="Model.CourseList" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The controller's action methods:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Student student)
{
    var viewmodel = new StudentVM {
        Student = student,
        CourseList = new MultiSelectList(
            _db.Courses,
            "Id",
            "Name",
            student.Courses
            .Select(sc => sc.CourseId));
    };
    return View(viewmodel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(StudentVM viewmodel)
{
    if (viewmodel.Student == null)
        return NotFound();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Student student = viewmodel.Student;
        var newCourses = viewmodel.CourseList
                         .Where(i => i.Selected)
                         .Select(c => new StudentCourse {
                             StudentId = student.Id,
                             CourseId = Convert.ToInt32(c.Value)
                         });
        student.Courses.RemoveAll(sc => !newCourses.Contains(sc));
        student.Courses.AddRange(
            newCourses.Where(nc => !student.Courses.Contains(nc)));
        _db.Update(student);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

Now come the questions...

### Question 1

When `StudentVM` comes into the `HttpPost` variant of `Edit`, both the properties are `null`. Why do the properties in the view model get cleared before entering the `Edit` function? I've confirmed they are being set correctly in the `HttpGet` variant, and that the data displays correctly in the view.

### Question 2

Since the data coming into `Edit` is invalid, I can't test my database updates. Is my method of getting the selected items from the `SelectList` and adding/removing items from `Student.Courses` correct? I haven't been able to find a lot of documentation regarding many-to-many relationships in EF Core.

I'm rather new to ASP.NET and Entity Framework, so any tips or criticisms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! That makes sense, and has solved my problem. If you submit as an answer, I'll mark it so. I also found [this documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html#the-select-tag-helper) helpful for other people with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `MultiSelectList` is. A `<select multiple>` element posts back an array of its selected option values (which in your case will be an array of the Courses `Id` values). Your model needs a property to bind to. Assuming he `Id` property of `Course` is `int`, then add the following property

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedCourses { get; set; }
```

Note also that setting the `selectedValues` property in the `MultiSelectList` constructor is ignored by the tag helper (internally the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` based on the value of the property. The code in your GET method should be

```
var viewmodel = new StudentVM
{
    Student = student,
    CourseList = new SelectList(_db.Courses, "Id", "Name"),
    SelectedCourses = student.Courses.Select(sc => sc.CourseId)   
};
return View(viewmodel);
```

Then in the view, use

```
<select asp-for="SelectedCourses" asp-items="Model.CourseList"></select>
```

And in the POST method, the value of `SelectedCourses` will contain an array of Course `Id` values that you selected in the view.